# class java.time.LocalTime cannot be cast to class java.sql.Time

Tags: java, mysql, connector-j

I get this error when doing a batch update using `setObject(int, LocalTime)` with the combination of url properties: `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` and `useServerPrepStmts=true`

[This says](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-connectorj-5-1-37-has-been-released/) that `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` and `LocalTime` have been fully supported since 2015 with JDBC 4.2, and I don't get the error without the above combination of url properties.

I don't see it listed as a bug fix ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-29.html), [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-30.html), or [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-31.html)) but can anyone confirm whether this should indeed work and if so whether it's still broken (with the above combination of properties) in versions of Connector/J 8.0.29, 8.0.30 or 8.0.31? I upgraded from 8.0.26 to 8.0.28 for the same issue with `LocalDate` which was already reported and fixed about a year ago ([mysql bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=105211)). And I see the same issue was reported/fixed about two years ago for `LocalDateTime` ([mysql bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=101413)). I don't know, maybe this is a good time of year to report the same issue for `LocalTime`?

Example code:

```
//MySQL 5.7
//Connector/J 8.0.28

String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname? 
rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useServerPrepStmts=true";

String sql = "INSERT INTO time_test(time) VALUES(?)";

try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql) ) {

    con.setAutoCommit(false);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ps.setObject(1, LocalTime.now());
        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    con.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();;
}
```

Exact error message:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.time.LocalTime cannot be cast to class java.sql.Time (java.time.LocalTime is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; java.sql.Time is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.setOneBatchedParameterSet(ServerPreparedStatement.java:759)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchedInserts(ClientPreparedStatement.java:712)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:426)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:795)
> at com.test.Test.main(Test.java:24)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us *your code*, *the exact error message* and ideally provide a [mre]. Judging just from the title, this could just as easily be happening somewhere in a object-mapping layer.

Comment: Is the column of the MySql [TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) type?

Comment: @g00se yup it is